# Confused about a review

Tags: support, stack-overflow, review, disputed-review-audits

I just tried to do a review. I tried to flag it as a duplicate because I felt it was a duplicate of a different question. I even Google'ed to be sure that it was a similar question, because I thought this question must have been asked before.

Why would I then have failed, to pass the audit?  I was taking the action I thought was appropriate by flagging it. I wasn't just clicking buttons, I did research on Google before deciding to flag it. If others didn't think it was a duplicate of the different question I would understand. But not passing an audit I don't understand?

Also the duplicate I was going to flag it as was the question that I was being audited on.  [Can javascript tell the difference between left and right shift key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22029033/can-javascript-tell-the-difference-between-left-and-right-shift-key)  That will teach me to Google.

Comment: I assume [this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/4227624) is the audit in question?

Comment: Yes that's it I just added my googled link :)

Comment: This is a problem with audits, it thinks you're trying to close as "Unclear" etc a post that "looks good" but it can't know that it might be a duplicate

Comment: All I did was click the flag button. I was going to flag it as a duplicate, of itself apparently.  Then I got "This was a high quality post and you should consider leaving it as it is or even upvoting"

Comment: @DaImTo: ah, so the duplicate you thought you found was the question itself? What made you miss it was the same post?

Comment: @DaImTo one suggestion is if you find something that is suspect (like a very obvious duplicate) in a review queue, it helps to click through to the actual post (instead of the audit page).  Once there, it would be obvious that the question is an audit and you can act appropriately in review,

Comment: The point it looked the same there for it was a duplicate.  I didn't check the dates. I didn't expect a trick.

Comment: @psubsee2003 that's the point, Just by clicking the flag button you fail the review.  I wouldn't have even gotten to the point of checking if it was a duplicate or not.

Comment: @DaImTo I never said click the flag button.  I said click through to view the entire post.  Every review has a link to the actual post.  When I am reviewing, I frequently open the actual post in another tab when I want more info on what I am reviewing or when I suspect I am looking at an audit.  If you had done that, you would have seen that your "duplicate" has 16 upvotes and was the same post you wanted to close as a duplicate of.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I tend to do that as a matter of course now if I'm not sure about a question or answer been stung by that before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Audits are picked automatically by the system. Sometimes that means it finds something that could reasonably be a closable post.

Don't sweat it, a single review failure once in a while will *not* be held against you. You can help improve the system by visiting that specific question and casting your duplicate vote on it anyway, and it'll no longer be eligible for review audits once you've done so.

Comment: Not really since now I'm locked out and cant review anything anymore.  Had one last week that I should have skipped as I didn't know the language. It looked decent to me. Apparently it wasn't, so now I'm guessing the system doesn't like me anymore.    The system should also be open to the option of someone flagging something as a duplicate of the Audit question being displayed. IMO.

Comment: @DaImTo: if you are review banned it is only temporary; you'll be allowed to review again in a week's time.

Comment: I know its just depressing, I feel like I have done something wrong. Makes me feel I should stop helping with reviews all together, but the hole point of stack was that we all help.  Which is one of the things I like.

Comment: @DaImTo: And no, the audit system doesn't need complications. Yes, it sucks when sometimes you fail one with what feels like the Right Thing, but if you are paying attention you'll spot an audit a mile away.